# Javascript/JQuery manual vs. mousewheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

this is my first post so if something is not right please say so.
I have a problem which i don't seem to find an answer for. Or I don't know what I need to search to find the answer.
The Task for me was to make a Table with a fixed head and fixed columns. I didn't find something on the internet that was fitting for my needs so i made something on my own (see link below).

http://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/gev3d0yx/

This works for me, but i have the big Problem that, when i scroll with the mouse wheel the head doesn't scroll along very good. The result after the scrolling is right but while scrolling the head is lacking behind.

I would love to hear some feedback and maybe a useful tip on how to fix that.
thank you in advance, nyxeen

Here is the code again if someone doesn't want the link:

Summery: An Object gets positioned when the parent is scrolled by the value that is scrolled. This works when using the scrollbar but when using the mousewheel it seems to lack behind.

```js
function init_fixed_table(){
 //Is a Table There?
 if($(".contains-fixed-table table").length<=0)return;
 var table = ".contains-fixed-table table";
 //Size it to Windowsize
 var swidth = $(window).width()-20;
 var sheight = $(window).height()-70;
 var dwidth = 40;
 var dheight  = 20;
 var rows  = 2;
 
 //Is there Data?
 if($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-width")!='' && $('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-width")!=undefined)dwidth=parseInt($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-width"));
 if($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-height")!='' && $('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-height")!=undefined)dheight=parseInt($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-height")); 
 if($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-rows")!='' && $('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-rows")!=undefined)rows=parseInt($('.contains-fixed-table').attr("data-rows")); 
 $('.contains-fixed-table').css("width", swidth+"px");
 $('.contains-fixed-table').css("height", sheight+"px");
 $(table).addClass("fixed-table");
 var i = 0;
 //Position Elements
 $(table).children("thead").children("tr").each(function(){
  var top = i*dwidth;
  $(this).css("top", top+"px");
  
  i++;
 });
 var top = i*dwidth;
 $(table).children("thead").css({"background":'white',"overflow":"hidden"});
 $(table).css("background", 'white');
 //Size Elements
 $(table).children("thead").children("tr").children("th").each(function(){
  var mwidth = dwidth;
  $(this).css({"width":mwidth+"px","height":dheight+"px"});
  $(this).css({"min-width":mwidth+"px","min-height":dheight+"px"});
  $(this).css({"max-width":mwidth+"px","max-height":dheight+"px"});
 });
 $(table).children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").each(function(){
  var mwidth = dwidth;
  $(this).css({"width":mwidth+"px","height":dheight+"px"});
  $(this).css({"min-width":mwidth+"px","min-height":dheight+"px"});
  $(this).css({"max-width":mwidth+"px","max-height":dheight+"px"});
 });
 
 
 
 $(table).children("tbody").prepend($(table).children("thead").html());

 //new table for horizontal movement
 $('.contains-fixed-table').append('<div class="new-fixed-left"></div>');
 
 var length=1;
 for(var j=1;j<=rows;j++){
  length+=$(".contains-fixed-table table thead tr th:nth-child("+j+")").width();
  length+=3;
 }
 
 $('.contains-fixed-table .new-fixed-left').css({
  "height":"auto",
  "width":length+"px"
 });
 $('.contains-fixed-table .new-fixed-left').append($('.contains-fixed-table').html());

 //scroll event moves thead and the new table
 $('.contains-fixed-table').scroll(function(){
  var curscroll = $(this).scrollLeft();
  var curscrollt = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(this).children("table").children("thead").css("top", curscrollt+"px");
  $(this).children(".new-fixed-left").children("table").children("thead").css("top", curscrollt+"px");
  $(this).children(".new-fixed-left").css("left", curscroll+"px");
  console.log(curscrollt);
 });
 



}

$(document).ready(function(){init_fixed_table();});
```

```css
table.fixed-table thead{
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:-1px;
}
table.fixed-table{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 margin-left:1px;
 z-index:50;
}

div.new-fixed-left{
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:100;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
div.new-fixed-left table thead{position:absolute;}
div.contains-fixed-table{
 position:relative;
}

table.fixed-table th, table.fixed-table td{border:1px solid black;}





   .contains-fixed-table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
   }
   table.data-table{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8rem;
    width:auto;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
   }
   
   table.table-text-right{
    text-align:right;
   }
   table.data-table th{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    min-width:80px;
   }
   table.data-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5efe3;
   }
   table.data-table th:first-child{min-width:250px!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="contains-fixed-table" data-width="70" data-height="20" data-rows="3">
   <table class="data-table table-text">
    <thead>
     <tr><th>Nennwert</th><th>E1</th><th>E2</th><th>F1</th><th>F2</th><th>M1</th><th>M1-2</th><th>M2</th><th>M2-3</th><th>M3</th><th>E1</th><th>E2</th><th>F1</th><th>F2</th><th>M1</th><th>M1-2</th><th>M2</th><th>M2-3</th><th>M3</th><th>E1</th><th>E2</th><th>F1</th><th>F2</th><th>M1</th><th>M1-2</th><th>M2</th><th>M2-3</th><th>M3</th><th>E1</th><th>E2</th><th>F1</th><th>F2</th><th>M1</th><th>M1-2</th><th>M2</th><th>M2-3</th><th>M3</th></tr>
     <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th><th><b>+/-mg</b></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>5.000 kg</b></td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td><td></td><td>8,0</td><td>25</td><td>80</td><td>250</td><td>800</td><td>800</td><td>1.600</td><td>2.500</td></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```